# Explicit Transformation of cross-capped disk $\cong \Bbb{RP^2}$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, functions, algebraic-topology, graphing-functions

**Context**

[Real Projective Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane)(contains the definition I'm about to mention) I'm interested in *visualizing* transformation between **closed** cross-capped disk, **sliced** cross-capped disk, and the self-intersecting disk, where the latter two objects are homeomorphic. So we have the following diagram to describe the relationship between these objects. Let $C$ denote the **closed** cross capped disk, $C_S$ denote the **sliced** cross-capped disk, and $D_I$ denote the self intersecting disk, homeomorphic to the sliced one, then,

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
[0,2\pi]^2/R_1 @>p\text{ (quotient)}>> [0,2\pi]^2/R_2\\
@Vq_1VV  @Vq_2VV\\
C_S @>f\text{ (quotient)}>> C\\
@Vg(\cong)VV        \\
D_I 
\end{CD}
$$
where $f:C_S\to C$ is a continuous quotient maps, and $g$ is a homeomorphism, and $R_1$ is generated by a $(u,0)\sim(2\pi-u,2\pi)$, while $R_2$ is generated by the relation in $R_1$ as well as $(0,v)\sim(2\pi,2\pi-v).$ where $u,v\in[0,2\pi]^2$

---

> **Questions:**
>
> **1. What is the parametric equation for a sliced cross-capped disk?** This question induced the folowwing one.
>
> **2. How to construct an explicit associative map for $k=f。g^{-1}$, that is $k_t=(f。g^{-1})_t:D_I\times[0,1]\to C$, where $k_{1/2}(u,v)=C_S$?** (I'm curious about this because I'm trying to use computer program to simulate the process in order to have a better visual understanding about real projective plane and also classification theorem)

---

**My Attempt**:

Recall the parametric equation for $C$
$$
\begin{cases}
x=r(1+\cos(v))\cos(u)\\
y=r(1+\cos(v))\sin(u)\\
z=-r\tanh(u-\pi)sin(v)\\
\end{cases}
$$
 and for $D_I$.
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=\dfrac{rv\cos(2u)}{2\pi}\\
y_1=\dfrac{rv\sin(2u)}{2\pi}\\
z_1=\dfrac{rv\cos(u)}{2\pi}\\
\end{cases}
$$

> The first one:
>   $$k_t(u,v)=(x-(x-x_1)(1-t),y-(y-y_1)(1-t),z-(z-z_1)(1-t))$$
>   But my program gives me a sequence of chaotic frames that show the discontinuous behavior of this transformation. You can see that the bottom of the surface is disconnected (the white part at the bottom). (see the figure below)
>
> [image]

Seems like this is not valid.

> The second one:
>   $$
> \begin{array}
> \\x(u,v,t)=r\dfrac{\cos(v)-(1-t)(\cos(v)-v)}{1-2(1-t)(1/2-\pi)}\big\{\cos{u}\big[1+2(1-t)(\cos(u)-1/2)\big]-(1-t)\big\};\\
> y(u,v,t)=r\dfrac{\cos(v)-(1-t)(\cos(v)-v)}{1-2(1-t)(1/2-\pi)}(2-t)\sin(u)[1+(\cos(u)-t\cos(u)-(1-t)];\\
> z(u,v,t)=?
> \end{array}
> $$
>   I don't know how to deal with that hyperbolic tangent function......

---

Any idea will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time and efforts. If there is anything unclear because of this long post, please let me know. :)

Comment: While the images and parameterizations on that wikipedia page are interesting for attempting to understand the problem of immersing the projective plane in $\mathbb R^3$, I don't think they are very helpful for understanding and visualizing the classification theorem (for that I would recommend something like Massey's "Algebraic Topology: An Introduction"). In particular, some of what you write is mathematical nonsense: quotient maps (like $f : C_S \to C$) which are not one-to-one do not have inverses, so your question 2 about constructing $k \circ f^{-1}$ does not make sense.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that I copied the wrong expression from my scratch paper......

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for your comment, I edited my post just now. I see that the inverse of a quotient map is nonsense but I still managed to use my first construction $C\times[0,1]\to D_I$ to reach the same resulting space... well, the problem is that the associative maps for both directions are chaotic and discontinuous which makes it an invalid construction, I'm kind of curious about which expressions should I use to visualize (represent) the transformation step-by-step......

Comment: I thought that the function could be like homotopy although these objects are not homotopic equivalent... so the associative map need not be continuous, but I still think that $k_t:D_I\times [0,1]\to C$ could be continuous.